# Switch has been removed from the Perl 5.14? what should I do?

Tags: perl, switch-statement

Is there any way to run scripts that includes `switch` statement with Perl 5.14?
I have many scripts that use switch statement, I do not want to run them on other perl's version. What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

[Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) has been deprecated and dropped from the standard distribution, but you can still install it yourself from CPAN.

Answer (score 7):

Prior to 5.10 there was a [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) module.  This is deprecated at 5.10 and replaced by a `given-when` syntax.  This [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-do-I-create-a-switch-or-case-statement%3F) describes it well.

The `Switch` module appeared in the core in 5.7.3 but was removed in 5.13.1

Comment: So, core module `Switch` appeared at `5.7.3`, and disappeared at `5.13.1`. From the FAQ: "Its use is now discouraged, because it's not fully compatible with the native switch of Perl 5.10." So in addition to core module there was a native construct? `given-when`?

Comment: @x-yuri: Under the `switch feature`, Perl gains the *experimental* keywords `given` , `when` , `default` , `continue`, and `break`. However, the `switch` feature is considered highly experimental; it is subject to change with little notice. See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) and [here too](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should rewrite the code that uses the deprecated and unsupported code and run everything else on an older `perl` until you've finished that. You can install the deprecated and unsupported module on a supported `perl`, but there's no guarantee that it's tricks will work anymore.